# Recipient Delivery Failed -- Webhooks and Correcting/Resending via the API

Tags: docusignapi

I've been working on an integration that sends an envelope to 2 signers. I am trying to test and program for the case of 1 of the signers having a bad email address. I would need to:

1. Be notified of this (webhook?)
2. Update the email address for the signer
3. Update the email address in the custom fields as that's printed on the agreement
4. Resend the envelope

When I enable the delivery failure notification in Connect (this is set up at the account level, for now), I don't see where the failure is noted in the webhook response or for which signer the error is happening.

I've found multiple links via Google talking about "correct and resend" but I haven't been able to get anything definitive in terms of what steps need to be taken or a (PHP) code example. I've also found "resend" in the API reference but still no code examples.

I also haven't seen any code examples (PHP) of how I would update a signer's email address and how that would work via the API.

It'd also be good to know how to update custom field data for both signers so the email address in the contract is updated (it's listed separately as part of the custom form data).

And finally, how would I resend the envelope?

Thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Per DocuSign support (customersupport@docusign.com):

1. Be notified of this (webhook?)
   I have updated your account settings and now you should be able to see AutoResponded in your webhook messages when email invalid or unreachable.
   *(my comments: so it sounds like you have to ask to be able to see this stuff, it's not part of their standard webhook responses)*
2. Update the email address for the signer
   I also haven't seen any code examples of how I would update a signer and how that would work.

Unfortunately we don't have an example for recipient update but the logic is to get list of all recipients, pick the one need to be updated, and update.

You can use below to retrieve all recipients per envelope
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/list/
GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/accountId/envelopes/envelopeId/recipients

Extract the one you need to update edit email and update using the below
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/update/
PUT /restapi/v2.1/accounts/accountId/envelopes/envelopeId/recipients

You can also see example code in C# how to do this in this thread https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/issues/307

3. Update the email address in the custom fields as that's printed on the agreement
   There is bug case created ( above link ) regarding this. **At the moment you can not update signer custom fields case EC-2944.**
4. Resend the envelope
   You can resend the envelope during recipient update

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/update/
PUT /restapi/v2.1/accounts/accountId/envelopes/envelopeId/recipients

*My commentary:
Since custom fields can't be updated, this whole use-case goes out the window.  We can't have contracts with incorrect data on it, so my client will have to do these corrections by hand.  Kind of a bummer.*